# Trying to set a div to visible in code using "style.visibility"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am trying to display this section

```
<tr>
  <div id="contact" class="uniForm" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">    
    <fieldset class="blockLabels">
      <legend style="font-size: 10pt;">Contacts</legend>
      <div class="ctrlHolder">
        <%= this.strContactInfo%>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</tr>
```

only if this condition is met:

```
if (iStatus == 2)
{
  lblAccessError2.Text = "Failure. ";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientscript1", "document.getElementById('contact').style.visibility = 'visible';", true);                 
  ModalPopupExtender1.Show();           
}
```

Comment: it stays hidden and does not become visible even when the condition is met...

Comment: and you have forget the `display:block`

Comment: The contact div will still not be visible because even though you set visibility to 'visible' the display is still set to none. You will need to change that to inline, or block, or just remove the none in your original style declaration and just toggle visibility via the visibility attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change the element's `display` rule also. You need to set it according to the `uniForm` class, or by default to `block`.

```
document.getElementById('contact').style.display = 'block';
```

For the record, [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/X9YNg/).

Answer (score 2):

In this line

`style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"` you have both visibility and display to non let display, but you change only the visibility, so the div is still stay hidden.

I suggest to use only one of them, or change them both, the visibility to visible, and the display to block.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose One**

`visibility: hidden` -- Don't display the item, but reserve its space on screen
`display: none` -- Make the item disappear entirely.

You don't need both.

To make the item appear, either, set `visibility` or `display` to an empty string `''` and it will revert to the default and the item will show up on screen.